# spring quartz pass property datasource

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I am building an scheduler application using Spring, Quartz, Maven. (doing for the first time).

The scheduler should connect to application database and update few records based on the business logic.

Now, the business logic is ready and application is running fine without scheduler.

While trying to integrating spring with quartz, I am getting confused on how to pass property like datasource.

Below is my files (configuration).

```
    public class AppMain {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        AbstractApplicationContext context = new  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("quartz-context.xml");}


And quartz-spring.xml looks like 

    <bean id="externalRequestService" class="com.abc.schedulers.service.ExternalEducationServiceImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="eduDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="myJobDetail"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.abc.schedulers.myJob" />
        <property name="jobDataMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="externalRequestService" value-ref="externalRequestService" />
                <entry key="mailService" value-ref="mailService" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="durability" value="true" />
    </bean>

 Corn Trigger like

    <bean id="cronTrigger"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="myJobDetail" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/5 21 * * ?" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetails">
            <list>
                <ref bean="myJobDetail" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

Now, when I run AppMain.java code.

    public class myJob extends QuartzJobBean{

    private MailService mailService = null;

    private ExternalEducationServiceImpl externalRequestService = null;

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext arg0)
            throws JobExecutionException {
        startEducationScheduler();
    }

    public void startEducationScheduler() {
        //IMailService mailService = context.getBean("mailService", MailService.class);
        mailService.sendMailToTeamBeforeAgentStart();
        System.out.println("I am here tooo.............");
        List<UserEducation> requestsWithUserEducation = externalRequestService.getUserEducationInformation();
        System.out.println("I am here tooo.222222222............");
}
```

The scheduler works till line "I am here tooo............" but after that it doesn't work.

Found the behavior is because of property value passed to externalRequestService at quartz-spring.xml i.e. datasource. And, without property passed, the scheduler works fine.

Could you please help on how to pass property like datasource to externalRequestService at quartz-spring.xml and get it worked? Should I use different spring and quartz class?

Please help.

Comment: Please add exception stack trace or other relevant information for the "doesn't work" part.

Comment: Hi Louis, I don't see any exception stack trace logged. It just stops executing after the line "I am here tooo............". Could you please let me know if I need to put "try catch block" inside startEducationScheduler()?

Comment: I would then look into what `externalRequestService.getUserEducationInformation();` does and how it could _block_. You should not need the try/catch block as an exception should bubble up and be reported.